# Not using TargetControlID for server control

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using two server controls that cause popups. One is cause by pressing a button. The second does not need to depend on an action event but happens programatically. Here is the code for the 2nd:

```
<div>
    <ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupChangeAssociations" runat="server" TargetControlID="Button1" PopupControlID="changeAssociationsPanel"
        PopupDragHandleControlID="PopupHeader" Drag="true">
    </ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
    <asp:Panel ID="changeAssociationsPanel" runat="server" CssClass="changeAssociationsPanel">
        <h2>This theme type is currently assigned to themes. What would you like to do?</h2>
        <asp:Button ID="removeAssignmentButton" runat="server" Text="Remove all Associated Assignments"
            OnClick="removeAssignmentButton_Click" />
        <asp:Button ID="changeAssignmentButton" runat="server" Text="Change all Associated Assignments"
            OnClick="changeAssignmentButton_Click" />
        <asp:Button ID="cancelAssignmentButton" runat="server" Text="Cancel" OnClick="cancelAssignmentButton_Click" />
        <asp:Panel ID="reassignPanel" runat="server" Visible="false">
            <asp:Label ID="reassignThemeTypeLabel" runat="server" Text="New Theme Type:"></asp:Label>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="reassignThemeTypeDropDown" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2"
                DataTextField="Type" DataValueField="PK_ThemeType">
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource5" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ApplicationServices %>"
                SelectCommand="SELECT [Type], [PK_ThemeType] FROM [ThemeType] WHERE [Deleted] = 0 ORDER BY [Type] ASC"></asp:SqlDataSource>
            <asp:Button ID="reassignThemeTypeSubmitButton" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="reassignThemeTypeSubmitButton_Click" />
        </asp:Panel>
    </asp:Panel>
</div>
```

There is a button attached to the second one which does not have to be. I don't need it, it's just there because if I remove it I get errors:

```
The TargetControlID of 'ModalPopupChangeAssociations' is not valid. The value cannot be null or empty.
```

I call it programatically:

```
        if (checkIfAssociationExist(sqlQueryReturnString(getThemeTypePK)))
        {
            ModalPopupChangeAssociations.Show();
        }
```

How do I get rid of the button so I can just use this particular server control programatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could assign it to a hidden field initially, and then change it programmatically to the desired control when needed.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure though, you can use label as your target Id. If no label is there then you can add a label and set visible property to false.